# I just mistakenly Hide my VS Code side bar

Tags: visual-studio-code, sidebar

[Click here to see the screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZyIV.png)

I just mistakenly my sidebar of visual studio code by right clicking on it. And not I can't find the way to get it back.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it back from **View>Appearance>**

[image]

Comment: I have done that but it is not coming back properly. Still I can't download the extensions and my git and others side functions are not visible. It is only showing the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly click View, then choose the appearance. You can see that there is a activity bar. You should active it. (Show activity bar). Same issue happened to me. This way helped me.

Comment: You haven't said anything here that wasn't already said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72914995/19068) from last year.